# How to do this linux command in windows?

Tags: linux, windows, command-prompt, libpq

Basically I'm trying to install libpq-dev but I've only found ways to do it in Linux. I've tried to install Cygwin but it takes quite a long time here at work, I currently don't have permanent internet connection at home, so I can't download at home.

Anyways, here is the Linux command that I'm trying to do in Windows:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libpq-dev
```

Please pardon my noobness in using the command-prompt.

Comment: Have you tried apt-cyg ? [Github apt-cyg](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg)

Answer (score 0):

There is [a manual for this](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html).
To install from package (recommended):

> Microsoft Windows
>   Jason Erickson maintains a packaged [Windows port of Psycopg](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/) with installation executable. Download. Double click. Done.

Comment: After installing, what do I do?

Comment: @JoshuaRajandiran: Whatever you were planning to do after installing the software. At that level of helplessness, you might want to consider going for a walk, or waxing your car instead.

Comment: Well this is a bit kinda late but, it appears that I already have libpq which is in my `lib` folder in PostgreSQL. I just needed to include the location in my system path, thanks for the help anyway.